# Refer to a component from its own listener if the component is local to a method

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

**NOTE** 
I apologize in advance for the verbosity of my question. I felt that it would be a better choice to describe the program rather than posting the entirety of my code.

Here is some background on my program to help aid in the description of my problem:

I am creating an assignment planner. A panel is split in half so that there are two sections, top and bottom. Two other panels are added, one for each half. The top panel is for ongoing assignments; the bottom is for the completed ones. Both of the panels hold containers, the assignments themselves, which hold different components (labels for date and description, an edit button, and a checkbox).

My problem lies in the ActionListener for the checkbox. The purpose of the checkbox is to move the container, aka the assignment, between the To-Do and Completed panels depending on if it is clicked. Because of this, the ActionListener needs to know the parent panel of the container so that it can act accordingly. Now I would use a field for the checkbox so that I could use the getParent() method on it directly, but there are multiple instances of the checkbox (since it is being created multiple times in the method that creates new assignments). As a field, the ActionListener always moves the first container, no matter if the checkbox clicked is from a different assignment.

Is there a way to refer to the checkbox in its own listener if it is a local variable? More specifically, could I get the parent container of said checkbox?

Here is the ActionListener (in the code posted, cb is a field for the checkbox):

```
private class CheckBoxListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int numOfParticularContainer;
            //System.out.println(parent + "\n" + toDoList);
            numOfParticularContainer = container.indexOf(cb.getParent());
            JPanel parent = (JPanel)container.get(numOfParticularContainer).getParent();

            if(parent == toDoList)
            {
                toDoList.remove(container.get(numOfParticularContainer));
                completed.add(container.get(numOfParticularContainer));
                toDoList.revalidate();
                toDoList.repaint();
                completed.revalidate();
                completed.repaint();
            }
            else if(parent == completed)
            {
                completed.remove(container.get(numOfParticularContainer));
                toDoList.add(container.get(numOfParticularContainer));
                toDoList.revalidate();
                toDoList.repaint();
                completed.revalidate();
                completed.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is a different question**

This question asks if a local variable can be accessed from an inner class.

The other question asks how you can figure out which element a container is in an ArrayList of JPanels.

The only reason getParent() was mentioned here was in the context of using it with a local variable. These are not related by a long shot. Just because I ask two questions about the same program does not equal a duplicate question.

Comment: Isn't the parent of the checkbox in the same class as the checkbox?

Comment: @L1ghtShadow Yes, it is. However, since the ActionListener is an inner class, I was wondering if you could do stuff with a local variable if said variable is what the listener is acting on.

Comment: I'd suggest a slight rethink, rather than the `ActionListener` making changes to the UI components directly, it should be making changes to a model, which is shared between the components, the act of moving an assignment from "to-do" to "completed" within the model would then trigger a change in state of the UI via some kind of observer pattern, this makes the `CheckBoxListener` independent of the rest of the API, as it only needs to act upon the model

Comment: How is this a duplicate? @camickr

Comment: It was explained to you how to use the getSource() and getParent() methods in your two previous questions. The problem is you refuse to post a proper [mcve] with your question, so we can't suggest where your coding problem is.

Comment: @camickr I understand how to use getParent(). the only reason it was mentioned here was in the context of using it with a local variable... See my edit to the question above for a more in-depth reason for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @camickr So could you look at my explanation and consider reopening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `CheckBoxListener` a parameter for a JPanel and when you add `CheckBoxListener` as a listener just put the JPanel you want as the parameter.

Example:

```
private class CheckBoxListener implements ActionListener
    {
        private JPanel parent;

        public CheckBoxListener(JPanel parent) {
              this.parent = parent;
        }
        //other methods
    }
```

Comment: I can't give it a parameter. CheckBoxListener implements an interface: ActionListener, which doesn't accept arguments.

Comment: Yes, a couple of days ago.

Comment: I must not have done it correctly then. Could you please add a snippet of code to your answer providing an example.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145751/discussion-between-john-eakin-and-l1ghtshadow).

Comment: @JohnEakin, `yeah i tried e.getSource() already, but i had to create a new checkbox in the inner class to do so` - no you are not creating a new checkbox, you are just getting the reference to the existing checkbox that was clicked!

Comment: @camickr The wording of that statement was, I'll admit, a little ambiguous. I meant that you are creating a new JCheckBox variable to get the reference. I don't remember what error I did come across while implementing your suggestion from a few days ago. But, I do know that I was unable to get it to work - attributable undoubtedly to me not understanding how to get it to work. Looking at the answer provided by L1ght, it seems his answer would have been the most simple, for me at least. Also, I urge you to look above to my explanation concerning the duplication mark. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JohnEakin, `I do know that I was unable to get it to work` - which is why you post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem instead of a wordy verbal description that may or may not describe the problem. We have no idea why you think you need a local  variable when the check box can be accessed directly in the ActionListener. This is how you write generic code by taking advantage of methods like getSource().

Comment: `This question asks if a local variable can be accessed from an inner class.` - so then ask a simple question in that context. You are asking a question and based on your history of questions you don't understand how to design your classes properly. So again, create a simple [mcve] demonstrating what you are trying. This example would have nothing to do with your application. Your question is confusing and 3 people have suggested using getSource() as a solution.